# Applying default style to all wpf windows

Tags: wpf

I've got a wpf application that has 20+ windows, most of which serve as dialogs, and I'd like them all to have the same background color.

I've got a typed style for Window defined in a resource dictionary as follows

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Grid Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}">
                    <AdornerDecorator>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </AdornerDecorator>
                    <ResizeGrip x:Name="WindowResizeGrip" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Collapsed" IsTabStop="false"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip">
                        <Setter TargetName="WindowResizeGrip" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I've got the dictionary include in the resources for the Application and each Window as follows

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Resources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Resources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

In Visual Studio, the background brush in the property editor says "Inheritance", but the value says "White".  I see the desired background color in Visual Studio, but when I run the application I still see a white background.  Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?  The WindowBackgroundBrush is getting applied to other controls correctly.

Note if I simplify the Style to be just

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua"/>
</Style>
```

Visual Studio shows the Background brush as "Style Setter" as the value source and shows the Aqua as the value source, but the window is still white when the app launches.

Comment: @EdPlunkett that's what the `<Application.Resources>` tag is doing.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I'm having a low IQ day. Sorry!

Comment: @EdPlunkett np. We all have those days ;-)

Comment: I have just tried to reproduce your problem and it happens to me as well. I remember that setting styles for windows is not as easy as it is for controls. It has something to do with `InitialiseComponents()` but can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Thanks.  Glad it's not just me.  Was the initial comment indicating that adding the dictionary to the windows resources is not necessary since its already added to the application resources?

Comment: It may not be quite what your after but we use a custom content control which we place as a wrapper within all windows. This control sits in a library we use for all our applications and provides styling for the window and through inheritance all the child controls. This means if we have a branding change then its just a case of updating the control and the apps get it automatically when rebuilt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did it all correct. Its working at my place ... How are you applying style to window ? I applied as follows..

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationScratchpad.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationScratchpad"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"  Style="{StaticResource Style1}">
```

here Style1 is your style in resource dictionary. with the name 'Style1'

```
<Style x:Key="Style1" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Grid Background="Beige">
                        <AdornerDecorator>
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </AdornerDecorator>
                        <ResizeGrip x:Name="WindowResizeGrip" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Collapsed" IsTabStop="false"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip">
                            <Setter TargetName="WindowResizeGrip" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Ok that works for me too.  I was expecting that the window would inherit the style because of it's type, like they styles I have for other controls I have defined, but I guess not.